# SurveyMonkey Webhooks - Request Type

Tags: api, webhooks, surveymonkey

When registering a webhook via the SurveyMonkey API, one of the parameters is a `subscription_url`. My question is: when SurveyMonkey fires the webhook, is it making `GET` or `POST` request to this URL?

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that SurveyMonkey will `POST` to your API endpoint. My issue was that SurveyMonkey will do a `HEAD`, before the `POST`, to ensure your API responds. So, to fix my issue, I had to add a `GET` endpoint that simply responds with a `200`.

Comment: Yes that's correct, SurveyMonkey always does a HEAD request at the time of creation of your `subscription_url` to verify it is accessible before successfully creating the webhook. After that as the event is triggered you will receive a POST request. This information should probably be specified in the docs.